# Inner join two tables on column1 like column2 followed by only non alphabets

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables - name_table:

| Id | name | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ssn_1 | int |
| 2 | ssn_12nam | varchar |
| 3 | ssn | int |
| 4 | ssn123 | int |
| 5 | ssnnam | varchar |
| 6 | ss123 | varchar |
| 7 | ss_12 | int |
| 8 | ssnam | varchar |

pattern_table:

| Id | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | ssn |
| 11 | ss |

I want to join the two tables on a condition name-like pattern followed by only non-alphabets.

```
select 
    A.name, B.pattern 
from 
    name_table A 
inner join 
    pattern_table B on A.name like B.pattern +'[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

Here `ssn` is matched with `ssn_12nam` - I only want name followed by non-alphabets or name = pattern. pattern ss should not match with ssn, ssn_123, etc.

This is the output I am looking for :

| name | pattern |
| --- | --- |
| ssn_1 | ssn |
| ssn | ssn |
| ssn123 | ssn |
| ss123 | ss |
| ss_12 | ss |

Comment: Then ss_12 should also be in the output?

Comment: yes, thanks. i have edited output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try joining on the following criteria:

```
select n.name, p.pattern
from name_table n 
join pattern_table p on Replace(n.name, p.pattern, '') not like '%[A-z]%';
```

You might find it easier to implement the logic in a *cross apply*:

```
select n.name, p.pattern
from name_table n 
cross apply (
  select pattern
  from pattern_table p
  where Replace(n.name, p.pattern, '') not like '%[A-z]%'
)p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The idea is to find 100% pattern match first and then find others using mask but exclude results with letters.

```sql
select 
    A.name, B.pattern 
from 
    tmp A 
inner join 
    pat B on 1 = case 
                    when A.name = B.pattern then 1
                    when A.name like B.pattern+'[^a-zA-Z]%' and replace(A.name,B.pattern,'') not like '%[a-zA-Z]%' then 1
                 else
                    0
                 end
```

[image]

Comment: No need for case when here, multiple join conditions can simply be used with OR.